# How can determine the time that a particular user has been actually using my application?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications

I have a web application deployed on Tomcat 8. I would like to track the time that a specific user has been using my application -- defined by how much time was spent by that user executing each request. That is, the time that effectively is working in the system.

Does such a feature already exist in Tomcat?

In Tomcat, I can already see that **Used Time** and **Inactive Time** are available to the [Tomcat Manager application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me9ty.png), but **used time** is not what I'm looking for: it merely subtracts **Creation Time** and **Last Accessed Time** giving a "total session effective age".

How can I determine the user's actual usage-time?

Comment: you should use a solution as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26427149/5655414 , as all you need to do at that point is just log out the current time. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a `Filter` that logs the time for each request and then adds that time to a user's aggregate usage-time. You could store that in the user's `HttpSession`, assuming there is already a session available.

Note that the user's cumulative usage-time will be lost once the session expires if you only store it in the session. If you want the information to survive session-expiration, you'll need to write the usage-time elsewhere such as a file on the disk or into a relational database.

The reference @angryip gives in the comment above is a good example of a `Filter`, but not a good example for how to actually time the request. The `doFilter` method of your `Filter` can be very simple. Something like this:

```java
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                     ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException
{
    HttpSession session = null;

    if(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)
        session = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getSession(false);

    // Start the clock
    long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Use try/finally because the request can throw an exception;
    // We still want to capture the usage-time even if an error
    // occurs.
    try {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } finally {
        // Stop the clock
        elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - elapsed;

        // Store the cumulative usage time in the session
        if(null != session) {
            Long usage = (Long)session.getAttribute("usage");
            if(null != usage)
                elapsed = elapsed + usage.getLong();
            session.setAttribute("usage", Long.valueOf(elapsed));
        }
    }
}
```

Getting the information out of the session is up to you. You can observe it using [JMX](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Monitoring) by requesting a session by its identifier and then calling "getAttribute" with an argument of "usage".

Comment: Thank you . But, more one question. This filter, can not leave the overloaded application? I thought there was something ready in TomCat.

Comment: No, Tomcat doesn't supply anything like this out of the box. Once built, you can use this `Filter` in any application you'd like, but it cannot be used reliably to aggregate usage across multiple applications (because the usage information is stored in the `HttpServlet`). If you store the usage info elsewhere, you can aggregate usage times from any number of applications, as long as you can figure out who the "user" is.